# Kubernetes oAuth2 with Auth0 ingress login redirect

Tags: kubernetes, oauth-2.0, kubernetes-ingress, auth0, nginx-ingress

I'm trying to deploy app into GKE with

- Nginx as ingress controller
- oAuth2 Proxy
- Auth0 as auth service

As this project does not have domain I need to setup ingress redirection basing on host ip.

oAuth proxy is deployed with Auth0 clientID, secret and domain provided on Auth0 project website.
In logs I can see that it it setup correctly but I cannot make login to redirection to Auth0.

When accessing any endpoint on my app this supposed to redirect user to login via Auth0, but instead of that I'm getting 500 code errors like:
`auth request unexpected status: 504 while sending to client, client: XXX.XXX.XX.X, server: _, request: "GET /oauth2/auth HTTP/1.1", host: "YY.YYY.YYY.YY"`

or

`connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: {...}`

I think problem is with ingress setup - with auth-url and auth-signin URLs.
I tried many different and right now it it looking right that:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: sky-ingress
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url: "http://$host/oauth2/auth"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-signin: "http://$host/oauth2/start"
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /offer(/|$)(.*)
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
            backend:
              service:
                name: sky-service
                port:
                  number: 5552
```

Normally `$host` will be domain but as I said I do not have it on this project I need to put ingress IP there.

Do I need to do something more in configuration like exposing it in ingress ?
Maybe anyone have similar to this (with no domain address) working setup on GitHub ?

Thank a lot for any help with that !

I tried a lot of different config I found on net, but nothing was working.